# Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress using angular.copy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an input field with a ng-blur function. My blur function uses Restangular to do a customPUT to the server and then does an angular.copy. It seems the line that causes the error is the angular.copy.

Input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="le.instance.from" ng-blur="blurField(le.instance.from, $event)">
```

Blur handler

```
$scope.blurField = function (fieldNewValue, event) {
   $scope.le.instance.customPUT({markSaved: true}).then(function(){
        angular.copy($scope.le.instance, $scope.leSaved);
    });
};
```

The line causing the problem is the angular.copy one. I understand what is this problem but I can't see why doing an angular copy causes another digest to be run...
I'm just copying my model object to another object.

Also on my controller I'm not using any call to $apply or $digest.

Any tips to understand / debug this?

Comment: Its a hunch that it is because you calling a function customPUT on $scope.le.intance and then trying to change it in the callback?

Comment: good hint but didn't solve. I replaced $scope.le.instance.customPUT with putTemp.customPUT where my putTemp is a new restangularizedElement that I created with no connection to $scope.le.instance

Answer (score 0):

You do make $digest process to run when you do angular.copy because you change model by doing it, one of the solution proposed very often by community is to use `$timeout` which will queue the copy for another digest

```
$scope.blurField = function (fieldNewValue, event) {
  $scope.le.instance.customPUT({markSaved: true}).then(function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      angular.copy($scope.le.instance, $scope.leSaved);
    })
  });
};
```